# Как cкопировать выходной файл в webpack в несколько мест?

Tags: webpack

В настройках output можно указать только 1 выходное место. А мне нужно помимо папки dist, скопировать в другое место на диске.

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')


module.exports = {

    context: path.resolve(__dirname , 'src'), // корень контекст

    // Точки входа
    entry:{
        home: './Home',
        //profile: './Profile',
        //shop: './Shop',
    },

    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname , 'dist')

    },
    plugins:[
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ],

    watch: false, // слежение за обновлениями
    devtool: 'source-map' // eval source-map
}
```

Умеет ли webpack такое делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не умеет, но можно использовать его возможности, добавить свой плагин, колбек которого будет срабатывать после определенного жизненного цикла, а именно после того, как `webpack` сгенерирует все в `output` директорию:

```
// webpack.config.js

const { copyFileSync } = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    ....

    plugins: [
        {
            apply: (compiler) => {
                compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap('AfterEmitPlugin', () => {
                    copyFileSync('./dist/bundle.js', './новая-директория/bundle.js')
                });
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Я так понял, что такой подход неправильный. webpack предназначен только для сборки проекта, а уже копирование или что то еще нужно делать с помощью других инструментов(например gulp).

Comment: если бы такой подход был неправильный, то плагинов не было бы в помине, а галп всего лишь менеджер задач

Comment: Тогда бы это было частью движка как в gulp и делалось просто.  Я так понимаю этот функционал специально не включают в webpack.

Comment: в галпе нет ничего сверхъестественного, исходный код галпа - это 50+ строчек кода, такой функционал и не подразумевается ни в одном бандлере, любой бандлер может иметь несколько входных параметров и один выходной (то есть один output), но есть много триков и обходных путей

Comment: А как узнать имя файла?
'./dist/build/static/js/[name].[hash:8].[ext].js'

Я использую create-react-app и там output такой
 output: {
    path: paths.appBuild,
    filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',
  },

Comment: И еще у меня пишет ошибку

yarn run v1.9.4
warning ..\..\..\..\package.json: No license field
warning ..\..\..\..\..\package.json: No license field
$ node scripts/build.js
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Cannot read property 'afterEmit' of undefined


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.